# Where can I find the deploy to users option after changing domain in my dev ed?

Tags: trailhead, custom-domain, mydomain

I didnt receive the activation email after successfully changing my subdomain (was able to log in using this new custom subdomain without activation email..)

Reason I'm trying to deploy to users is I keep getting this error message in trailhead challenges>

There was an unhandled exception. Please reference ID: TOLOOUUU. Error: Faraday::ConnectionFailed. Message: getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

(so I'm not able to verify challenges synced to my dev ed sf)

Any help would be much appreciated..

Answer (score 0):

Wait for 5 to 10 min once your domain is registered. Deployed link will be available.

Thanks

Comment: the thing is, I did the change yesterday, and still didn't receive any email regarding the activation and unfortunately now, I'm  even unable to change the custom subdomain for the second time to trigger the new activation email request..